# odi-12.2.1.3.0 unable to create an instance of the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: oracle

I have successfully installed odi-12.2.1.3.0, but when I run it, it displays this error:

> Unable to create an instance of the Java Virtual Machine Located at path: C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll

[image: error message Unable to create an instance of the Java Virtual Machine]

Comment: Perhaps your machine doesn't have enough memory. If you have other processes running maybe close some memory hogs. Or edit the ODI conf file to use less memory: `AddVMOption -Xmx512M` (or whatever). Alternatively the conf may have the wrong JDK path

Answer (score 0):

try to do this go to C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk\jre\bin\server and copy this file jvm.dll and paste this file in this path C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk\jre\bin\client but before you paste it make backup from jvm.dll in client folder if the path dose not exist try the  path  in the error massage

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple solution i have personally tested all you need to do is the following

1. download the missing file from the below url
   https://www.dll-files.com/download/f86b5057928fddd315f9a9f46357003e/msvcr100.dll.html?c=OGhpL0hDOUw2bzRrNk1ySDRxc0I1dz09
2. place the downloaded file in the designated error message path and thats it reopen ODI

100% working

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but when I encountered this exact same error message today, I found the below article from Oracle stating "The odi.conf file contains a location for a 32-bit Java JDK". I installed the 64 bit version of jdk and jre from Oracle then manually updated the product.conf file (c:\users<username>\AppData\Roaming\odi<version>\product.conf) to point to the 64 bit version and relaunched ODI Studio. It worked at this point.

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/1501490_1.html

I hope that this helps someone else having this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

I managed to fix it by installing a 64bit jdk and updating the jdk path.

Link: https://www.oracle.com/webapps/redirect/signon?nexturl=https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u301-b09/d3c52aa6bfa54d3ca74e617f18309292/jdk-8u301-windows-x64.exe

Answer (score -1):

Download the missing msvcr100.dll from https://www.dll-files.com/msvcr100.dll.html and place it in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin

Hint: Download the latest version

Answer (score -1):

I face same issue and i tried above solution but did not resolve my problem. But when i updated my JDK from 32 to 64 bit. it works for me.

We need [64bit Java JKD (Java SE Development Kit 8u171)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html).

Product / File Description: Windows x64
File Size: 207.27 MB
Download: jdk-8u171-windows-x64.exe